# Can i deploy a war that contains a JAR dependence?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, maven-2, maven-3, jboss7.x

Can I deploy my web maven project knowing that it has a dependency to an EJB maven project? Or do I have to create a EAR where I will package both of them and then I will be able to deploy them?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you do not have to create an EAR. Java EE Web profile supports packaging EJBs into a WAR, either in /WEB-INF/lib or /WEB-INF/classes. So since you have a separate EJB project, just place it into the /WEB-INF/lib. Since you're working with Maven, just list your EJB project as a dependency to your web project.

**Update**

Since you're working with maven, your EJB project's `pom.xml` will contain the `<artifactId>`, `<groupId>`, and `<version>` for that project under the root element. Just copy those three to you web project's `pom.xml` under the `<dependencies>` element. Then when you build your web project, maven will automatically bundle your EJB  project in the correct place in the WAR.

Comment: i place the war or the whole project..and plz im new to all this..how can i place it into the /web-inf/lib ???

Comment: Yes im working with maven..i add the ejb jar as a dependendy (pom.xml)but nothing is working :/

Comment: @Nadia if you have problems with maven, you should include in your question the maven conf that you're trying

Comment: @Nadia Indeed, do what eis is saying. Note, that the EJB project has to be built at least once for it to exist in maven's local repository.

Comment: yes absolutely i even use mvn clean every single time i try to build the web project :/

Comment: @Nadia I believe you have to do a mvn install on your EJB project as well, see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/

Comment: @rdcrng:i do every time "clean install" ( Maven build) and its ok beacuse i get a WAR ou Jar ..as far as the pom.xml ,i use the Maven POM editor and i add the EJB jar..when i see the POM source i find the Three element of EJB project are addet...

Comment: When i deploy my WEB project i get an error caused by "Can't find a deployment unit named ModuleEjbPU at deployment xxx.war"..My persistence.xml is in my ejb project..help plz :///

Comment: Ok, so the problem may not be with maven at all. Can you verify if your EJB jar is inside the WAR by simply cracking it open? Anyhow, **I'm not sure** the container will pick up a persistence.xml from inside /WEB-INF/lib/ejb.jar!META_INF/. You might have to move your persistence unit to the WEB-INF folder.

Comment: thank you for ur patience, i tried to copy/paste the persistence.xml file into web inf folder of my Web project but nothing seems working

Answer (score 0):

i figure out how to add the Jar into WEB-INF/lib
  1.Add the jar file to your WEB-INF/lib folder.
  2.Right-click your project in Eclipse, and go to "Build Path > Configure Build Path"
  3.Add the "Web App Libraries" library

This will ensure all WEB-INF/lib jars are included on the classpath.

Thanks anyway for ur help

Comment: you did not mention anywhere that you wanted help with eclipse :)